# Deluxetable column header carrying over to next table

Tags: tables, longtable, columns

I have two tables, one is a `deluxetable` and the second is a landscaped `longtable`. The column header from the first table is being carried over to the second table, such that the second table has two rows of headers (see image below). I've tried clearing the page, forcing a new page, etc. but nothing seems to help. Also, as a result, the second table is no longer seen as a separate entity, hence the "Table 1 Continued." Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint,revtex4]{emulateapj}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{deluxetable}{llllllll||ll}
  \tablehead{
\colhead{Thing A} &
\colhead{Thing B} &
\colhead{Thing C} &
\colhead{Thing E} &
\colhead{Thing F} &
\colhead{Thing G} &
\colhead{Thing H} &
\colhead{Thing I} &
\colhead{Thing J} &
\colhead{Thing K} \\
  }
   \vspace{1mm}
B & B & B & B & B & B & B & B & B & B \\
  \enddata
\clearpage
\end{deluxetable}


\clearpage


\tiny    %{|  p{3.9cm}  |  p{0.7cm}  | p{10.0cm} |}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable} {|p{2.0cm}|p{4.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{2.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|}
%\hline
\bf{Stuff 1} & \bf{Stuff 2} & \bf{Stuff 3} & \bf{Stuff 4} & \bf{Stuff 5} & \bf{Stuff 6} & \bf{Stuff 7} & \bf{Stuff 8} & \bf{Stuff 9} & \bf{Stuff 10}  & \bf{Stuff 11}\\
\hline
\hline
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
\end{longtable}
\clearpage
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a documented feature of the class that you are using that longtables can not be used in this way.

The comments at the start of `emulateapj.cls` include:

```
%% 3) Multi-page tables cannot be set properly inside the main text; you
%% need to move the table to the end of the paper (after the references) and
%% issue the command \LongTables before it.
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments, unfortunately 1) the table is already at the end of the paper after the references, 2) I have another `longtable` later in the document which does not experience this issue, and 3) adding `\LongTables` did not solve the issue.

Comment: @cosmosis sorry but the class looks like it makes several changes to the longtable code I've no idea why it does that

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help. I may be able to move the order of the tables to avoid this issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reset the headers from the first table by using `\endhead` instead of `\\` in the first line of your `longtable`, such as:

```
\bf{Stuff 1} & \bf{Stuff 2} & \bf{Stuff 3} & \bf{Stuff 4} & \bf{Stuff 5} & \bf{Stuff 6} & \bf{Stuff 7} & \bf{Stuff 8} & \bf{Stuff 9} & \bf{Stuff 10}  & \bf{Stuff 11}\endhead
```

Comment: `\bf` is a switch, not a macro that takes an argument. Also, it's deprecated in lieu of using `\bfseries`. See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)